# GREP - Search only in first n characters of each line, searching for number after special character

Tags: grep, numbers, max, output, netstat

my first post here.

In summary: I have a netstat output, using "netstat -an" command in Windows, and I would like to get the top number of one of the columns.

The output of netstat is something like this:

```
  TCP    10.45.43.232:50387     10.42.48.61:902        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    10.45.43.232:50559     46.228.47.115:443      CLOSE_WAIT
  TCP    10.45.43.232:52501     10.48.48.128:3389      ESTABLISHED
  TCP    10.45.43.232:58000     10.46.48.243:63713     ESTABLISHED
```

The result I want is:

```
58000
```

That number is the biggest value on the second column, after the ":" character

So, in essence, I want a grep (and/or sed, awk, etc) which can search through a file, only look in the first 25 characters of each line, and get the highest number after a ":" character.

Tell me if you need more information, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be an approach:

```
netstat ... | sort -t':' -nrk2 | awk -F"[ :]" '{print $8; exit}'
```

By pieces:

Sort it based on `:` as delimiter and taking second column into account:

```
$ netstat ... | sort -t':' -nrk2
  TCP    10.45.43.232:58000     10.46.48.243:63713     ESTABLISHED
  TCP    10.45.43.232:52501     10.48.48.128:3389      ESTABLISHED
  TCP    10.45.43.232:50559     46.228.47.115:443      CLOSE_WAIT
  TCP    10.45.43.232:50387     10.42.48.61:902        ESTABLISHED
```

Print the biggest:

```
$ netstat ... | sort -t':' -nrk2 | awk -F"[ :]" '{print $8; exit}'
58000
```

Or better, using [Mark Setchell's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22658545/1983854) to fetch the last item:

```
$ netstat ... | sort -t':' -nrk2 | awk '{sub(/.*:/,"",$2); print $2; exit}'
58000
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!!

I marked fedorqui answer as correct, because I can't mark any as useful due to reputation, but the ones that I combined to my solution are fedorqui's and Mark Setchell's.

Answer (score 1):

if the output has leading space/tabs:

```
netstat...|awk -F':|\\s*' '{p=$4>p?$4:p}END{print p}'
```

if there is no leading spaces:

```
netstat ..| awk -F':|\\s*' '{p=$3>p?$3:p}END{print p}'
```

Comment: Do you have a spare shoulder I can borrow to cry?

Answer (score 1):

I would go with this:

```
netstat -an | awk '{sub(/.*:/,"",$2); if($2>max)max=$2} END{print max}'
```

The `sub()` part strips all characters up to and including a colon, off the second field thereby extracting the port. If that is greater than `max`, `max` is updated. At the end, `max` is printed.

Answer (score 1):

Here is yet another way using `GNU awk`:

```
netstat ... | awk '{split($2,tmp,/:/); a[tmp[2]]++}END{n=asorti(a);print a[n]}'
```

- We split the second field of second column (delimited by `:`) in a `tmp` array
- We populate the values as `keys` in array `a`.
- In the `END` we use `GNU` awk `asorti` function which `sorts` the `keys` and print the highest.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it with coreutils alone:

```
netstat ... | cut -d: -f2 | cut -d' ' -f1 | sort -nr | head -n1
```

Output:

```
58000
```